# Discord.py `on_user_update` does not work, even with intents enabled

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to print the username + discriminator of a when they update their avatar/username/discriminator, but nothing happens when I update my own username, avatar or discrim. I have also made sure to enable intents on `https://discord.com/developers/applications/(my application id)/bot` My code is:

```py
import discord


intents = discord.Intents().all()

client = discord.Client(Intents=intents)



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))



@client.event
async def on_user_update(before, after):
    print(str(after))


client.run('my token')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyword arguments are case-sensitive, the keyword argument for client intents configuration is `intents`, not `Intents`. So the client instance must be:

```py
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```